# Show that $(\mathbb{Z}_6,+_6) \cong (\mathbb{Z}_3,+_3) \times (\mathbb{Z}_2,+_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n:=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ define $a +_n b$ as addition modulo $n$.

> Show that $(\mathbb{Z}_6,+_6) \cong (\mathbb{Z}_3,+_3) \times (\mathbb{Z}_2,+_2)$.

To show that these structures are isomorphic, we must show that there exists an isomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2  \to \mathbb{Z}_6$. Would the function $(a,b) \mapsto 3a +_6 4b$ work If I show that it is bijective? I'm also having trouble using the homomorphism property $f(a \ast b) = f(a) \Box f(b)$ since its defined for two binary operations $\ast$ and $\Box$ and in this case we have have three ($+_2,+_3$ and $+_6$).

Comment: Yes, $3a+4b$ is the Chinese remainder theorem result searching for $x\equiv a\pmod 2$ and $x\equiv b\pmod 3$, which is what you want.

Comment: For your last point, there aren't actually three operations, just $+_6$ (in your notation) and the $+$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. This operation does indeed involve componentwise $+_2$ and $+_3$, but is to be considered as a single entity.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this makes it more clear.

Comment: You can also start from $\mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$ by defining $x(\mod 6) \mapsto (x(\mod 2), x(\mod 3)).$ This is basically inverse of the map that you have defined.